# Highlight top 3 values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot like this with the following code:

```
aus_cases <- ggplot(data = daily_cases,aes(x= date, as.numeric(V1)))+
  geom_col(fill = 'blue', alpha= 0.6)+
  theme_minimal(base_size =14)+
  xlab(NULL)+
  ylab(NULL)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

And I wanted to highlight the top 3 value within the plot and show the date in the plot as well, was thinking to use gghighlight but am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `ggplot2::economics` dataset as example data you can highlight and label the top 3 values like so:

1. Add an indicator for the top3 values to your df using e.g. the `rank` function.
2. To highlight, map the top3 indicator on fill.
3. To add the dates use geom_text to add labels only for the top3 values

Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Example data
d <- filter(economics, date >= as.Date("2010-01-01"))

# Add top3 indicator
d <- mutate(d, top3 = rank(-psavert) %in% 1:3)

ggplot(data = d, aes(date, psavert, fill = top3)) +
  geom_col(alpha = 0.6) +
  geom_text(aes(label = ifelse(top3, as.character(date), "")), nudge_y = .1) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "red", "FALSE" = "blue")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14) +
  xlab(NULL) +
  ylab(NULL) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the help. however, the date the highlight were overlap as the point are too close to each other. Any idea I can solve this problem so I can show the date clearly and is it possible to show the case number as well? Thank You!

Comment: One option would be to the `ggrepel` package. `ggrepel::geom_text_repel` makes use of an algorithm which does its best to prevent overlapping labels (and labels overlapping the data).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. You didn't `dput`your data, therefore I used this test data.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(gghighlight)

daily_cases <- data.frame(V1 = c(10,20,30, 10, 5, 10, 10, 40, 50, 10),
                 date = ymd("2020-02-01", "2020-02-02",
                            "2020-02-03","2020-02-04",
                            "2020-02-05","2020-02-06",
                            "2020-02-07","2020-02-08",
                            "2020-02-09","2020-02-10"))
```

At first I specified the top 3 values and their date in `top`. And used  these information in `ggplot` in gghighlight (highlighting the three bars) and scale_x_date (just show the dates of the highlightes bars).

```
top <- daily_cases %>%
  arrange(desc(V1)) %>%
  slice(1:3) 


aus_cases <- ggplot(data = daily_cases,aes(x= date, as.numeric(V1)))+
  geom_col(fill = 'blue', alpha= 0.6)+
  gghighlight(V1 >= min(top$V1)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 14)+
  xlab(NULL)+
  ylab(NULL)+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_x_date(breaks = top$date, date_labels = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Here is the plot.

[image]